# custom advance search issue in Yii

Tags: php, yii, bootstrapping

i have implemented my project in Yii. i done  search part its working fine. but i want advance search. i am getting all values except one field from the table. please suggest me what i need to change. i added my code here.

my controller part:

```
public function actionAdvancesearch()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Recipe']))
        $as=$_POST['Recipe']['recipe_name'];
        //var_dump($as);
        $model=new Recipe;
        if(isset($_POST['Recipe']))
           {

            $name=$_POST['Recipe']['recipe_name'];
            $course=$_POST['Recipe']['course_id'];
            $cuisine=$_POST['Recipe']['cuisinename'];
            $type=$_POST['Recipe']['type'];
            $calorie=$_POST['Recipe']['calorie_count'];

        $this->redirect(array('advancesearch1','course'=>$course,'cuisine'=>$cuisine,'name'=>$name,'calorie'=>$calorie,'type'=>$type));
           }

     $this->render('advancesearch',array('model'=>$model
            ));    
        }

public function actionAdvancesearch1()
    {
            $model=new Recipe;
            $name1=$_GET['name'];
            $course1=$_GET['course'];
            $cuisine1=$_GET['cuisine'];
            $type1=$_GET['type'];
            $calorie1=$_GET['calorie'];

    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Recipe']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Recipe'];

            $this->render('advancesearch1',array( 'course1'=>$course1,'cuisine1'=>$cuisine1,
            'name1'=>$name1, 'type1'=>$type1,
                'calorie1'=>$calorie1
                    ));

   }
```

my view part am just print the values but name field only not showing null values..

i added my URL values also

```
http://localhost/kitchenking/index.php/recipe/advancesearch1/course/3/cuisine/3/name//calorie/1/type/1
```

above URL name values are empty.. not fetching from the table. and also tryed var_dump().. which also saying that name return NULL values..

Answer (score 2):

```
public function actionAdvancesearch1() {

   $model=new Recipe('search');
   $model->unsetAttributes();

   // do stuff here 

   $this->render('advancesearch1', etc....

}
```

Don't forget the unsetAttributes while using search

Answer (score 0):

for yii to search your models you need to use "search" scenario

change

```
public function actionAdvancesearch1()
    {
            $model=new Recipe;
```

to

```
public function actionAdvancesearch1()
    {
            $model=new Recipe('search') ;
```